# Need to find expectation of the prize in the game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, algorithms, expected-value

Player plays game, where he starts with $i$ tokens, and there are also $n$ tokens "at all".
Game lasts $t$ rounds at most.
At every round player wins one more token with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, or he loses one (with probability $\frac{2}{3}$).
There are 3 cases when the game ends:
1)The player is out of his tokens (which were $i$ by the start)
2)Player got all the n tokens
3)There were $t$ rounds played
When game ends, player gets his prize with size $prize = 2^{result}$, where $result$ is amount of tokens player got by the end of the game.
Need to find expectation ($E[prize]$) of the prize.
Please, could you give me any ideas of solving the problem? I have tried to use binomial distribution to solve that problem, but it doesn't fit really good as it seems to me.
By the way, this problem was met in my "algorithm and data structures" course (which is over already), so may be the problem has some decision related to one?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: First step is to **experiment**, letting $n$ run from 3 to 5, and for each $n$, letting $i$ run from (perhaps) 2 to $(n-1).$  For each experiment, you might consider letting $t$ (perhaps) run from 3 to $n.$  Chart each experiment and look for **patterns** in the chart.  Use the patterns to **formulate a conjecture.**  Then try to prove the conjecture.  **As is**, your problem will probably be **closed**, because you haven't **shown any work.**  If you do the work I am suggesting (or some other line of attack that you choose) **then please show this work in your query.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $2^k$ with $k$ the number of tokens is a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)). If the player has $k_n$ tokens before a round, the expectation of $2^{k_{n+1}}$ with $k_{n+1}$ the number of tokens after the round is

$$
\frac132^{k_n+1}+\frac232^{k_n-1}=2^{k_n}\;.
$$

Thus the expected prize is $2^i$.